# AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'image_dim_ordering'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried to execute some tutorial transfer learning project.
But I've got attribute error.

I checked my tensorflow and keras version.

tensorflow : 1.14.0
keras : 2.2.5

and python 3.6.9 version.

the code is here.

```py
if(K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th'):
  input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
```

error message here.

```py
AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'image_dim_ordering'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`keras.backend.common` module has `image_dim_ordering()`

```
if(K.common.image_dim_ordering() == 'th'):

    input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
```

Comment: K.common.image_dim_ordering()  by default is set the ordering to tf ordering. How can I change it to ´th´?

Comment: it doesn't work anymore, no image_dim_ordering() anywhere

Answer (score 9):

Replace `image_dim_ordering` to `image_data_format`

```
if(K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th'): 
  input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
```

change the above code to

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'th':
  input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
```

[Keras Backend utilities](https://keras.io/api/utils/backend_utils/)

Comment: Hello Vidya Ganesh, can you improve the formatting of your answer please?

Comment: This worked for me as of march 2021 :) Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Self answer for who has same issue with me.
image_dim_ordering change to image_data_format from Keras 2.x.
Since change image_dim_ordering to image_data_format.

reference link

- https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12649
- https://keras.io/backend/

Answer (score 3):

It specifies which dimension ordering convention Keras will follow. To confirm what your keras is using check your Keras configuration file at:

~/.keras/keras.json

In file if contents are

```
{
    "floatx": "float32",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "backend": "tensorflow",
    "image_data_format": "channels_last"
}
```

then make changes to

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
```

If file contents are

```
{
    "image_dim_ordering": "tf",
    "epsilon": 1e-07,
    "floatx": "float32",
    "backend": "tensorflow"
}
```

then make changes to

```
if(K.image_dim_ordering() == 'th'):
  input_tensor = Input(shape=(3, 299, 299))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to change the format to channels_firs:

```
keras.backend.set_image_data_format('channels_first')
use this to check your format:
 keras.backend.image_data_format()
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem also.

The easy solution is to replace `image_dim_ordering` to `image_data_format`.
The new command line will look like the one below.

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'th':
```