# How to fix "AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute.."

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

Code:

```
from keras import backend as K
K.set_image_dim_ordering('tf')
```

Error:

> `AttributeError: module 'keras.backend' has no attribute 'set_image_dim_ordering'`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error : keras.backend has no attribute 'set\_image\_dim\_ordering'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785863/error-keras-backend-has-no-attribute-set-image-dim-ordering)

Comment: [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57797113/9758790) may be related to your question, too. Please include more information like the version of `keras` and python.

Answer (score 1):

You are importing `backend` from `keras` as `k`. Your code should read: `keras.k` Or you should import the module like this:

```py
from keras import backend
```